# Docker image not found during local deployment ("no such image")

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to test my service and to do so I deploy it locally and until now everything worked fine. However, for some unrelated reason I was forced to delete all my docker images and since then I'm unable to deploy the service locally. Upon deployment I receive the following error:

> 404 Client Error: Not Found for url:
>   http+docker://localnpipe/v1.39/images/471b7320d98e95ad137228efff17267535936b632a749f817dbee3e9d03cd814/json

And also:

> ImageNotFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("no such image: 
>   471b7320d98e95ad137228efff17267535936b632a749f817dbee3e9d03cd814: No
>   such image:
>   sha256:471b7320d98e95ad137228efff17267535936b632a749f817dbee3e9d03cd814")

What I did to deploy the model:

```
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.webservice import LocalWebservice
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig

ws = Workspace.from_config("config.json")

deployment_config = LocalWebservice.deploy_configuration(port=8890)

inference_config = InferenceConfig(runtime= "python", 
                               entry_script="score.py",
                               conda_file="env.yml")

model_box = Model(ws, "box")
model_view = Model(ws, "view_crop")
model_damage = Model(ws, "damage_crop")

service = Model.deploy(ws, "test-service", [model_box, model_view, model_damage], inference_config, deployment_config)

service.wait_for_deployment(True)
```

I understand why there is no image present, but I would expect that it is downloaded in that case.

Is there a way to force the build process to re-download the docker base image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the problem and corresponding solution:

I deleted all images but there where still some containers based on deleted images present. Deleting the corresponding container had the desired effect that the docker image is reloaded from the server.

You can delete all containers with `docker kill $(docker ps -q)`.

Comment: Hi , I am a code very similar to yours. but I encountred a diiferent problem in the Model.deploy step. the service is created but when i do docker ps -a, i found that the service is exited with Code 111 after 3 seconds from Created and Up statues. Do you have any idea about it maybe ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint on this @thomas, has same "docker not found" issue on local deploy for testing, and solved with docker container prune -f